# Breaking arrays into windows/chunks with cumulative sum less than a reference value , and excluding few windows with other constraints

Tags: arrays, windows, matlab, chunks

This is not a duplicate. 
I have an array of 36000 cells, i want to break those arrays into windows of cumulative sum less than a reference value. and exclude few windows based on other parameters respective to this array based on index.  For example A= [ 0.5 0.6 .45 .56 .056 .16 .18 .10 .15 .45 .36]; similarly other arrays of same length.
Now window 1 should start with 1st value and end at sum less than 2 ( window{1} = [0.5 0.6 .45], sum = 1.55) second window has to start from 2nd value ( window{2} = [0.6 .45 .56 .056 .16], sum = 1.826).
Similarly i need all possible windows for 36000 cells, while excluding those where value/sum of other arrays/windows of respective index.
Index of these windows is also needed 
**I here wanted a moving window. Eg Index of my windows would be like [ 1 3] , [2 6], [3 9], [4 10], [5 11], [6 11], [ 7 11], [ 8 11], [9 11], [10, 11]. If i don't wont to consider values in index 3,4, 8, i want to exclude windows which include these indexes**

Comment: @rahnema Nope, that looks little different. I here wanted a moving window. Eg Index of my windows would be like [ 1 3] , [2 6], [3 9], [4 10], [5 11], [6 11], [ 7 11], [ 8 11], [9 11], [10, 11].    If i don't wont to consider values in index 3,4, 8, i want to exclude windows which include these indexes

Comment: You are right the problem is a liitel different. I prepared an answer but unfortunately the thread is locked. You can see the answer in this link: http://rextester.com/XEWXB75719

Comment: Since your array has 36000 elements you may encounter memory problems, so you can use this  loop based solution:http://rextester.com/BSNV79392